# Export as HTML then Excel crashes suddenly afterwards

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following code to export a range from a sheet "sourceSheet" and save it as "TargetSheet.html" in the same folder. The problem is a few seconds after each time I run it when I save the file or open another Excel or do some other operations, Excel crashes! And there is no way to retrieve the file and go back one step.

```
Sub ExportHtml()
 Dim rng As Range

 file1 = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "TargetSheet.html"

 Set rng = Sheets("SourceSheet").Range("A1:FP15000")

 ActiveWorkbook.PublishObjects.Add( _
 SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
 Filename:=file1, _
 Sheet:=rng.Worksheet.Name, _
 Source:=rng.Address, _
 HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic).Publish

End Sub
```

Please let me know if this code is faulty / why running this code causes so much trouble afterwards?